# Node.JS mongoose request with Q promise return empty {}

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, q

Using mongoose and Q for promises. But result is empty {}

```
var Q = require("q");

var deferred = Q.defer();

User.find({}, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
        deferred.reject(next(err));
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(users);
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Same request with mongoose promise return correct data, but has strange order complete:

```
console.log("Label 1");
console.log("Label 2 Users = " + getUsers());
console.log("Label 3");

...

getUsers = function(next) {
    User.find({}).exec().
        .then(function (err, users) {(
            if (users) {
                console.log("Label 4 Users = " + JSON.stringify(users));
                return user;
            }
        )}
        .catch(err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}
```

Result:

Label 1 -> Label 2 -> Users = undefined -> Label 3 -> Label 4 Users = {...}

Node.Js v7.5; mongoose v4.8.3; q v1.4.1

Where is mistake? What way can I use to call mongoose in function?

Comment: where is your callback? All i see is the next(err). Also, why don't you use mongooses build in promises in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have grasped the concept of asynchronous execution. "Asynchronous" means the result isn't available right away. You need to return the promise from your `getUsers` function (and fix your typo):

```
getUsers = function(next) {
    // v---- here
    return User.find({}).exec().
        .then(function (err, users) {(
            if (users) {
                console.log("Label 4 Users = " + JSON.stringify(users));
                return users;
            }
        )}
        .catch(err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}
```

And then wait for it:

```
getUsers().then(function (users) {
    console.log("Label 1");
    console.log("Label 2 Users = " + users);
    console.log("Label 3");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the mongoose v4.8.3 you don't need q any more, use the mongoose promise directly

```
User.find({})
    .then((user) => {
        console.log(users);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```